# Unable to use arrow key in Textfield inside MenuAnchor Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't move cursor inside textfield using arrow keys but other than that is working fine like TextEditingController, styling.

```
MenuAnchor(
  controller: _menuController,
  menuChildren: [
    const TextField(),
  ],
  builder: (context, controller, child) => TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
      if (controller.isOpen) {
        controller.close();
      } else {
        controller.open();
      }
    },
    child: ...
  ),
);
```